# How to give certain system access without giving local admin access?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I am seeking advice on how I can accomplish the following tasks without giving certain groups local admin rights on the servers.

- Ability to query the status of all the Windows Services
- WMI access
- Ability to read all Event Logs
- Ability to query status of all services
- Enabling remote PowerShell commands

The servers I need to give this type of access to are Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Std Edition and Windows Server 2003.

Any advice and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an admin account you can give permissions to other non admin users in order to execute the tasks.

WMI:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787533(v=ws.10).aspx

Event Logs:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/04/30/giving-non-administrators-permission-to-read-event-logs-windows-2003-and-windows-2008.aspx

Service Query:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782435(v=ws.10).aspx

Remote Powershell:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Hope that this suits you.

Comment: Sorry about the links, i Don't have sufficient reputation :)

Comment: Even though the links do answer the questions, the Stack Exchange model prefers that you take relevant snippets from the sources and post them in the answer and present the links as citation for further reading. A user should see a stack exchange answer and not have to click a link to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite a lot of work to grant admin level permissions to query all services, event logs and definitely PowerShell commmands. That's not to say it's impossible, but even when you cobble together various methods of doing it - you have to replicate that across all your servers reliably.

Full disclosure: My company has a product (not free) that makes it easy to do everything you've mentioned.